# Is it possible to create a view where deleted rows in the original table are kept

Tags: database, view

I have a table `COMPANY` where companies are kept. I want to create a view of that table, let's name it `COMPANY_CDC` but with one caveat:

When an entry in the original table is deleted, I want to set a `deleted` flag on the view entry instead of deleting it.

**EDIT** Why soft deletes? The point is that im performing change data capture using JDBC, and JDBC is only able to capture soft deletes. Inserts / updates are no problem.

If this cannot be done by using a view, what would be an alternative solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can insert deleted values in another table using trigger
, and with join of these two table you can create your view.